# Mysql: How to match stored Regex column value with the passed Query parameters

Tags: java, mysql

Mysql:  Hot to match stored Regex column value with the passed Query parameters.

I have a table called user_access

```
    user_access 
    1. id
    2. userId
    3. url
```

it contains the data like

```
 
    id userId    url
    1   1    service/v1/users/[^/?#]+
    2   1    service/v1/users/[^/?#]+/notes
    3   1    service/v1/users/[^/?#]+/notes/[^/?#]
    4   2    service/v1/users/[^/?#]+/notes
    5   2    service/v1/users/[^/?#]+/notes/[^/?#]
```

I want to check that if user 1 is accessing url  service/v1/users/1 then he has valid url regex entry in table.

In mysql i know that we can match regex

```
    select 'service/v1/users/1' regexp ' service/v1/users/[^/?#]+';
```

If I know user_access ID then it can be done with

```
    select 'service/v1/users/1' regexp  (select url from user_access where id=1);
```

Issue is I know only user id(1) and for it we have three entry in user_access table. 
 If i run query

```
    select 'service/v1/users/1' regexp  (select url from user_access where userId=1);
```

Returns error code 1242. Sub query returns more than one row.

Comment: can you post your query ? and post the expected outputs(s).

Comment: @Ravi  I want to have this kind of query.
 select * from user_access  where 'service/v1/users/1' regexp url == 1

Comment: you should share the expected data instead. what you want may not be feasible or correct.

Comment: <pre>
     select * from user_access  where 'service/v1/users/1' regexp url == 1
<pre>
My goal is to check given url is present in DB. I have stored url regex in DB. Because url are dynamic and will change based on data.
<br>
If we take url service/v1/users/{userId} , {userID} will be replaced with actual userId for each user. I can't store all users url in DB so i have stored as service/v1/users/[^/?#]+'  means for any user .
<br>
now i have url with me like service/v1/users/1  and i want to check that is is match with my db stored regex url .
Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this SQL: `select * from user_access where 'service/v1/users/1' regexp url = 1`